# How can I concat columns as null-safe?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT(u.user_fname, ' ', u.user_lname), 'unknown') name
FROM users u
WHERE id = 10;
```

The result will be `unknown` when either `user_fname` or `user_lname` is null. That's not what I want, I want to select `unknown` only when both `user_fname` and `user_lname` are null.

Otherwise, I want to get the value of not-null column. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Use `concat_ws()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', u.user_fname, u.user_lname) name
FROM users u
WHERE id = 10;
```

This has the nice benefit that if either of the names are `null`, you don't get a spurious space in the result.

It gets a little tricky if you want to convert `NULL`s to "unknown".  This should do the trick:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(CONCAT_WS(' ', u.user_fname, u.user_lname) , ''), 'unknown') as name
FROM users u
WHERE id = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
SELECT COALESCE(
         TRIM(CONCAT(COALESCE(u.user_fname,''), ' ', COALESCE(u.user_lname,''))),
        'unknown') name
FROM users u
WHERE id = 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

I always like the isnull function in sql server (or nvl in oracle):

```
SELECT isnull(u.user_fname + ' ','') + isnull(u.user_lname, '') name
FROM users u
WHERE id=10
```

but then to switch include the Nulls, I would use a case:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN u.user_fname IS NULL AND u.user_lname is NULL THEN 'unknown'
ELSE isnull(u.user_fname + ' ','') + isnull(u.user_lname, '') END name
FROM users u
WHERE id=10
```

yes, it's a little longer than the other answers, but easier to read and perhaps more flexible in the future in case you have other conditions.

Not really a performance hit either way, so it's down to personal preference.

Comment: @PaulX . . . The standard function is `COALESCE()` and this is available in basically all databases.